Are convex functions not uniformly continuous?
My question is about a convex and increasing function defined over $[0;+\infty[$.
I know that we can construct such a function $g$ so that it is uniformly continuous, for example $g$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, g(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^3}$ and $g$ linear on [n, n+1].
However let's suppose that our function $f$  is not linear on any segment, is $f$ then not uniformly continuous ?

That function isn't convex, it is concave.

isn't something like $f(x) =x^2$ already a counterexample?

I believe a concave increasing continuous function is always uniformly continuous.

@GeorgeCoote I think, from the body of the question, OP has confused concave and convex.

Actually, my statement is wrong, because I was assuming a domain of $[0,+\infty).$ On the whole real line, you'd need more than that to get uniform continuity.

So, $1-e^{-x}$ is uniforrmly continuous on $[0,+\infty)$ but not all of $\mathbb R.$

My question is about convex functions not concave, does this means that since all concave funtions are uniformly continous, convex functions are not ?

The answer to your question is no ; 
A convex function is uniformly continuous on $[0,+\infty[$ if and only if its right derivative are bounded, if and only if it is lipschitz. 
$(\Leftarrow)$ is not too hard to prove. For $(\Rightarrow)$, just use that the right derivative is increasing. 

To find a counter-example to your question, take a convex function, picewise linear whith bounded right derivative (for example, a primitive of your function $g$). Then do the convolution of $g$ with a positive function, with a support of length $>1$. Then the convolution is convex, lipschitz, but will be nowhere linear (the right derivative will be nowhere constant).
